# Android Layout Inflater not working?

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have an inflater in my main java class, mainly because I want to be able to 'findViewById' in a layout other then the one set in 'setContentView' (activity_main.xml).

Since I'm new to Android dev and Java in general, I thought I could do this with a layout inflater. Anyway, the layout I'm trying to inflate a layout named "box_middle".

This is my code where I create the inflater (and try to use it).

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.box_middle, null);

    drawerGrid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
```

I am initialising "drawerGrid" like this (public)

```
 GridView drawerGrid;
```

The end result is nothing shows up where the GridView in the XML code is.

Here is the XML code (box_middle)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- Card visible layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_main_layout"
    style="@style/card.main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="142dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:background="#ffff0c00">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Compound view for Shadow
       If you want to customize this element use attr card:card_shadow_layout_resourceID -->
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.component.CardShadowView
    style="@style/card.shadow_outer_layout"
    android:id="@+id/card_shadow_layout"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

BTW I'm using Android Studio and [this](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/) library.

Answer (score 5):

You use

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.box_middle, null);
```

to inflate the view, but you don't attach it to the window. Don't forget to use `this.setContentView(view);`

All the code should be :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.box_middle, null);
this.setContentView(view);`
```

Comment: This works, but the result is the view switching to the view "box_middle", it's meant to be on the view "activity_main". Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You can set the visibility of the view "box_middle" to `gone`. But you can't find a view if she isn't attach to the window. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your main class extends Activity you can also use findViewById...

like that (But be sure that before you must setContentView' (activity_main.xml) )

drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);